# Why is an integer being promoted via an explicit constructor?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

[This code](http://ideone.com/F5o8Fm)

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint32_t ticksPerSecond = 100000;

struct timemeasure {
    constexpr explicit timemeasure(uint64_t c) : ticks(c) { }
    uint64_t ticks;
    constexpr timemeasure() : ticks(0) { }
};

struct time : timemeasure {
    static volatile time now;

    constexpr time() : timemeasure() { }
    explicit time(uint64_t c) : timemeasure(c) { }

    // Needed for `x = time::now`
    explicit time(const volatile time &t) : timemeasure(t.ticks) { }
    time& operator=(volatile time t) { ticks = t.ticks; return *this; }
};

inline time foo(const time& t) { return time(t.ticks + 1); }
```

gives the compilation error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘time foo(const time&)’:
prog.cpp:22:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘time::time(time)’
prog.cpp:22:57: note: candidate is:
prog.cpp:14:15: note: constexpr time::time()
prog.cpp:14:15: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Why is `time::time(time)` trying to be called? Surely the `uint64_t` is not allowed to be promoted?

Comment: Why all the `volatile` in the example? Is `now` updated by multiple threads?

Comment: @Casey: It's updated by one thread, and read by others.

Comment: Is c++11 an option? Using `std::atomic` for `now` would avoid all that mess with the volatile copy and assignment operator ([like this](http://ideone.com/mRiXMm)).

Comment: @Casey: I'm using C++11, but I'm not sure std::atomic will work in the context of interrupt handlers.

Comment: If your implementation can do atomic 64-bit writes, then `std::atomic<uint64_t>` should be lock-free and you are ok. If your implementation can't do atomic 64-bit writes, then `volatile uint64_t` may see torn writes.

Comment: @Casey: What stops the compiler keeping local copies of the variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32095/discussion-between-casey-and-eric)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy constructor of `time` is marked as `explicit`, and when returning a value from a function, a temporary is *copy-initialized* from that value. Paragraph 8.5/15 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> ```
> T x = a;
> ```
>
> as well as in argument passing, **function return**, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception
>   (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.5.1) is called *copy-initialization*. [...]

However, constructors marked as `explicit` are not considered in the context of a copy-initialization (see 13.3.1.4/1 and 13.3.1.5/1), hence the error.

Comment: Just came to that conclusion myself

Comment: @Eric: I know that feeling, asking others is often the best way of *really* asking yourself ;)

Comment: The answers is correct on the reason, but fails on the argument. The issue is not with the constructor that takes the `uint64_t`, that constructor is called **explicitly** in the code. The problem is with the copy constructor being `explicit`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's true, although at the time I started working on the answer, the code in the question contained another function returning `x` of type `uint64_t` (and the return type of the function was `time`). I failed to see the updated. Anyway I edited the answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `time` by value from `foo` since `time` has no accessible copy constructor: the constructor from `volatile const time&` does not match. Throw in a:

```
time(const time&) = default;
```

Comment: It would match, but isn't checked because it's `explicit`.

Comment: @aschepler Not according to [gcc 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/ZwCO6t): `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘time’ to ‘const volatile time&’`